# Cannot stop Postgresql in FreeBsd Jail

Tags: postgresql, freebsd, jail

I installed postgresql in a jail, it starts automatically after adding `postgresql_enable="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf`), but now I can't stop it.

I tried `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/postgresql stop`, but I've got:

```
pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
```

But of course it is runnging, I can connect to it using `psql`, also when I do `ps ax|grep postgres` I get:

```
15411  -  SsJ  0:00.07 postgres: logger process    (postgres)
15412  -  SsJ  0:00.05 postgres: startup process    (postgres)
15413  -  SsJ  0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer process    (postgres)
15414  -  SsJ  0:00.02 postgres: writer process    (postgres)
15415  -  SsJ  0:00.00 postgres: stats collector process    (postgres)
15410  2  SJ   0:00.17 /usr/local/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

I need to gracefully stop it from a script, how can I do this?.

**Edit:**

I think the init scripts are confused because my `data_directory` is different the default `ConfigDir`, in fact, the *PID* file is created in my `data_directory` which points to `/mnt/postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `postgresql_data="/mnt/postgresql"` to `/etc/rc.conf` and leaving the `data_directory` field as default (commented and pointing to `'ConfigDir'`:

```
#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'
```